# Lisp, How to remove list of elements from list?

Tags: list, lisp

Is there a built in (no external library) way to remove a list of elements from a list?

```
(remove-elements '("a" "b" "c" "d") '("b" "c"))
```

to:

```
("a" "d")
```

or do you have to write your own function, and if so how would such a function look?

Comment: That doesn't look like Lisp syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order is not important, use the [`SET-DIFFERENCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_di.htm) function:

```
(set-difference '("a" "b" "c" "d") '("b" "c") :test #'string=)
```

Comment: However, the result is not guaranteed to preserve the order of the first list.

Comment: @davypough True, but in many cases where you need to do something like this, the order is not significant.

Comment: OK, but the original question concerned lists rather than sets. I probably would prefer something like (remove-if (lambda (elt) (member elt '("b" "c") :test #'string=)) '("a" "b" "c" "d"))

Comment: I've added a qualifier. If you want to post another answer, feel free.